# How to create a new database by passing the db name as parameter value with azure database configuration

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a new database by passing a parameter value to the db name

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_dbCreation] @dbname nvarchar(30)
AS
CREATE DATABASE [@dbname] (EDITION = 'Standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ELASTIC_POOL (name = [xxx]), MAXSIZE = 250 GB) WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```

but my database is getting created with the name @dbname instead of the value I am passing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use variables to replace a literal. `CREATE DATABASE [@dbname];` **literally** means create a database with the name `@dbname`, *not* create a database with a name of the value within `@dbname`. Just like you wouldn't expect `SELECT '@dbname'` to return the value from within `@dbname` but instead return the literal value `'@dbname'`.

The only way to do this is with dynamic SQL, however, I would personally suggest that if you have this kind of requirement, you have a design flaw.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_dbCreation] @dbname sysname AS --sysname is the correct data type for an object name
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
    SET @SQL = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N' (EDITION = ''Standard'', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ELASTIC_POOL (name = [xxx]), MAXSIZE = 250 GB) WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response it works fine now .... But can you elebrate why this is causing design flaw it will be helpful for me .... And my requirement is like I will be creating the database using NodeJs API call like this (http://localhost:9000/api/dbcreation/test/customer) where customer is the db name which I am trying to pass through an API and that name is used as the parameter value

Comment: Because you're doing what I suspected, and using the database name to infer information that should be a column; must likely you should have a company table in your database, and then data should be linked to the company and row-level security should be implemented. Perhaps partitioning on certain tables as well. I hope you never need to answer a question that involves getting data from every companies tables.